# Unit test outputs per test case are not shown properly in PyCharm

Tags: python, unit-testing, pycharm

I have some unit tests written in Python using the `unittest` package. The tests run fine, but when I run them in PyCharm, I have the following problem:

When I click on `TestResults` on the left menu, it shows all the outputs properly. But when I click on individual test cases, the output is not shown properly. More specifically, at the level corresponding to a test case class, part of the output is shown, but at the level of one specific methods (the ones starting with `test` in their names), no output is shown at all.

Any idea why this is happening and how I might be able to fix this?

I am using:

```
PyCharm Community Edition 2016.1.4
Build #PC-145.1504, built on May 25, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_77-b03 x86
JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM by Oracle Corporation
Python 2.7
```

on Windows.

---

EDIT 1: The failures are shown properly, but not the std out.

EDIT 2: An example to reproduce what I mean:

```
import unittest


class SuperSetup(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        print "set up class"

    def setUp(self):
        print "set up test"

    def tearDown(self):
        print "tear down test"

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        print "tear down class"


class Test1(SuperSetup):
    def test_nothing_new(self):
        print "testing nothing 1!"
        self.assertEquals(1 == 1, True)

    def test_something_new(self):
        print "testing something 1!"
        self.assertEquals(1 == 0, True)


class Test2(SuperSetup):
    def test_nothing_new(self):
        print "testing nothing 2!"
        self.assertEquals(2 == 2, True)

    def test_something_new(self):
        print "testing something 2!"
        self.assertEquals(2 == 0, True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Is it something for a bug report? Or am I missing something?

Comment: It works well for me, have you configured your test runner properly?